# Spotfire Terr - Date and DateTime conversion

Tags: r, date, datetime, spotfire, terr

I'm trying to write a simple R script that passes in a Document Property of type Date, creates two new date variables that are +/- 180 days from the original date, and passes the new dates out to a Document Property of type Date.

I've tried various iterations on the script, and have had success if the output variables sent to a Document Property declared to as type DateTime, however, I need them to be of type Date.

For example, this script worked (but output is DateTime, which doesn't suit my needs):

```
jobDate <- as.POSIXct(jobDateFromJobSelectionMarking)

#Subtract and add 6 months from job date (time is in seconds)
jobDate6mBefore <- (jobDate-15552000)
jobDate6mAfter <- (jobDate+15552000)
```

I tried the following script in RStudio and had success (i.e. the output variables are of class Date), but when I bring it into Spotfire/TERR I get the error: "Changing datatype of an existing property is not allowed. Old datatype: Date, new datatype: Real"

```
jobDate <- as.Date(jobDateFromJobSelectionMarking)

#Subtract and add 6 months from job date (time is in days)
jobDate6mBefore <- as.Date(jobDate-180)
jobDate6mAfter <- as.Date(jobDate+180)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on Tibco Community site:
[Link to Q&A](https://community.tibco.com/questions/spotfire-terr-date-and-datetime-conversion)

It appears that the conversion from DateTime to Date as described in the question above is unavoidable.

See [Tibco Support article](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/ka11a000000HsvpAAC/What-TERR-object-class-does-the-Spotfire-data-function-framework-recognize-as-date-time-information?_ga=2.63823407.1612669397.1502792270-324413183.1467334866) that discusses some details of Date and Time transactions between TERR/R and Spotfire.